# Is there a secure way to connect to Active Directory from internet?

Tags: vb.net, login-control, insecure-connection

I am creating a website and my company feels accessing active directory from internet can be a security threat. I would like the users to be able to log in using Active Directory Credential. Is there a secure way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Active Directory Federation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) might be what you're looking for. Specifically the "Web Single Sign On" functionality.

Since you've tagged with question with "insecure-connection" I feel I must add that you **should not**, under **any circumstances** let user account data flow in to or out from your company's firewall un-encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) is based on the emerging, industry-supported Web Services Architecture, which is defined in WS-* specifications. ADFS helps you use single sign-on (SS0) to authenticate users to multiple, related Web applications over the life of a single online session. ADFS accomplishes this by securely sharing digital identity and entitlement rights across security and enterprise boundaries.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736690%28v=WS.10%29.aspx